# Need a function for the following...

Tags: functions

I'm trying to come up with a function formula for $y$, that is a broad curve that passes through $(0,0)$ and almost crosses $(100, y)$ but never does. ( so $x <  100$)

Can you please help me?

PS. $y \ge 0$, though that is probably irrelevant to this scenario.

Comment: How about a drawing of the graph you want?

Comment: What do you mean by "almost cross" $(100,y)$? And this $y$ is the same as your curve $y$?

Answer (score 1):

how about $ f(x)=x^2\sqrt{100-x}$